# Windows 10 remote desktop delay after rebooting or waking from sleep

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

whenever I reboot my computer or wake up from sleep via a magic packet on my Windows 10 desktop, there's a 2-3 minute delay before I can RDP into it via my Mac. Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: If you could figure out how to monitor the event viewer and find the appropriate event the WOL/magic packet logs in the event viewer, you could potentially trigger a scheduled task on this event id and have that do something to help fully wake up the PC and maybe do a short ping to a network resource, etc. Just a thought of something potentially easy enough to test to see if triggering something on the OS event helps. Otherwise I'd suggest the usual; update to the latest hardware firmware/BIOS, and ensure your NIC drivers are up-to-date just in case there's patches at these levels.